# Using SQL server for scientific use: what data type?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to bring some scientific data over from MS-Access to MS-SQL and have run into a data type issue that stymies me. There are some data about weights of mice (in grams). Sometimes the weight collected is 3.45 (2 decimal places), for example. Other times it might be 14.567 (3 decimal places). Still other times it might be 1.20. When the data were collected they were collected at a particular precision (2 or 3 decimal places). But because of this 1.20 does not equal 1.2 -- it's critical to maintain the original precision.

When converting these data which are stored in Access as "Numbers", I have only two choices -- I can bring the data over as real or float, or I can bring them as numeric or decimal. Real or float are approximations and sometimes add unwanted precision (I've seen 0.75 come across as 0.74999672, or something like that). But the decimal/numeric option forces me to specify how many decimal places I want, and since those vary, if I choose the maximum scale it will append trailing zeros on the values that are less precise, making it impossible to know at what precision the datum was originally collected.

I could maybe create additional calculated string columns in Access for those data that are numeric, import the data as strings and that would preserve the precision, I think. but I'd still have to store them as strings in SQL because as soon as I'd try to convert them to numeric I'd have the same problem.

To be clear, this has I think little to do with whether the data originated in MS-Access or are entered somehow directly into MS-SQL using a web form or some other interface -- the issue is how the data are stored in SQL and how they could be formatted for display.

It's hard for me to believe that SQL doesn't have a way of storing a number in a column exactly the way it was collected. Am I missing something here?

Comment: How does 1.20 not equal 1.2 ?

Comment: In SQL Server and (IIRC) Access 1.2 is stored the same as 1.20 in all numeric data types.

Comment: Sounds like you've got 2 choices. Add an additional column for weight precision that indicates the precision of the original measurement or treat it as a string.

Comment: David, thanks for that -- if I know that Access data have the same problem that would help me explain. There are some 75 numeric fields in the database and I'd have to add a second column for precision to each of them if I took Martin's suggestion.

Comment: "It's hard for me to believe that SQL doesn't have a way of storing a number in a column exactly the way it was collected." That's nevertheless the case. T-SQL has no types that embed precision on a per-value basis -- but neither does Access, so whatever precision you think you'd lose on conversion is already not present. Check the properties of the columns you're using to store those numbers -- specifically, "precision", "scale", "decimal places" and "format". I'd be surprised if you could have "1.2" and "1.20" in the same column.

Comment: Note that programming languages like VB or the .NET framework do support this scenario, because their `Numeric`/`Decimal` types are floating-point decimal types which embed the scale used on a per-value basis, so you *can* have `1.20` and `1.2` as separate values. Database numeric types tend to be fixed-point only. If you need to do calculations in the DB itself, a separate precision field would work, but if you don't, the way of least resistance is probably a string. In both cases, you have to take special care with calculations where numbers with different precisions are involved.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. You are apparently right on all points, and what you say about taking care with calculations on numbers with different precisions is critical. The issue is that in certain domains not only the value but also the precision at which it was originally collected or measured (lab measurements, measurements in the field using various instruments) needs to be preserved. In this case they used access and so they don't have that precision anyway. In the future I'd consider creating a user-defined type with fields for both.